# Appending, avg list, dict, key

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to learn Python, and I got stuck on one of my practice problems.

- Answered* First question: I understand how to get the average of a list, but is there a better loop to use?

Second question: In my second function, why am I not appending the `int`s greater than zero in `x`?

Instructions:

> Implement the following three functions (you should use an appropriate
>   looping construct to compute the averages):
>
> - allNumAvg(numList) : takes a list of numbers and returns the average of all the numbers in the list.
> - posNumAvg(numList) : takes a list of numbers and returns the average of all the numbers in the list that are greater than zero.
> - nonPosAvg(numList) : takes a list of numbers and returns the average of all the numbers in the list that are less than or equal to zero.
>
> Write a program that asks the user to enter some numbers (positives,
>   negatives and zeros). Your program should NOT ask the user to enter a
>   fixed number of numbers. Also it should NOT ask for the number of
>   numbers the user wants to enter. But rather it should ask the user to
>   enter a few numbers and end with -9999 (a sentinel value). The user
>   can enter the numbers in any order. Your program should NOT ask the
>   user to enter the positive and the negative numbers separately.
>
> Your program then should create a list with the numbers entered (make
>   sure NOT to include the sentinel value (-9999) in this list) and
>   output the list and a dictionary with the following Key-Value pairs
>   (using the input list and the above functions):
>
> - Key = 'AvgPositive'  :  Value = the average of all the positive numbers
> - Key = 'AvgNonPos'  :  Value = the average of all the non-positive numbers
> - Key = 'AvgAllNum'  :  Value = the average of all the numbers Sample run:
>
> Enter a number (-9999 to end):  4 Enter a number (-9999 to end):  -3
>   Enter a number (-9999 to end): -15 Enter a number (-9999 to end):  0
>   Enter a number (-9999 to end):  10 Enter a number (-9999 to end):  22
>   Enter a number (-9999 to end):  -9999
>
> The list of all numbers entered is: `[4, -3, -15, 0, 10, 22]`
>
> The dictionary with averages is: `{'AvgPositive': 12.0, 'AvgNonPos':
>   -6.0, 'AvgAllNum': 3.0}`

```
def nums():
    values = []

    while -9999 not in values:
        x = int(input("Enter any amount of numbers or -9999 to quit: "))

        values.append(x)
    values.remove(-9999)

    return values

def allNumAvg(values):
    average = 0
    sum = 0
    for n in values:
        sum = sum + n
        average = sum / len(values)

    return average

def posNumAvg(values):
    x = []
    average = 0
    sum = 0

    if int in values > 0:
        x.append(int)

    print(x)

print(posNumAvg(nums()))
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Much more readable.

Comment: Sorry I was curious if there was a better loop to use.

Comment: Why not just `return sum(values)/len(values)`?

Answer (score 0):

Your `allNumAvg` function needs a change:

```
def allNumAvg(values):
    average = 0
    sum = 0
    for n in values:
        sum = sum + n

    # this shouldn't happen inside the loop
    average = sum / len(values)

    return average
```

I'm not sure why you would write that and not just `return sum(values)/len(values)`, though.

Comment: Thank you for that edit. I didnt realize you could return a formula! Learning new stuff everyday!

Comment: It's not really any more or less a "formula"... It's just shorter code.

Comment: OK i just didnt realize you could return anything more than a variable i guess.

Comment: @TYPKRFT Think about it like `return <expression>`. You might be used to only returning a variable, like `average`, but actually `average` is also an `<expression>`, namely, the value of `average`.

Comment: Should I make another question for my second question? Sorry I am not sure about the etiquette of the site.

Comment: I think that would make more sense, yes.